# Парсер записывает в csv данные 3 раза

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv

имеется код, записывает указанные данные 3 раза.

```
title = 'car 2007'
price = '237.000 RUB'
url = 'yummy.ru


data = {'title': title,
 'price': price,
 'url': url}
 
 
 
with open('yummy.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
 writer = csv.writer(f)
 writer.writerow(('title', 'price', 'url'))
 for i in data:
   # results = data['title', 'url', 'price']
   writer.writerow((data['title'], data['price'], data['url']))
```

вывод

```
title,price,url
car 2007,237.000 RUB,avito.ru
car 2007,237.000 RUB,avito.ru
car 2007,237.000 RUB,avito.ru
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in data:
   # results = data['title', 'url', 'price']
   writer.writerow((data['title'], data['price'], data['url']))
```

Так как ключа в словаре `data` 3, то и записывается 3 раза одно и тоже.
В данном случае: уберите `for`

```
writer.writerow((data['title'], data['price'], data['url']))
```

`for` нужен в том случае, если у вас, допустим, **список словарей**:

```
data = [{'title': 'lol', 'price': '0', 'url': 'kek'},{'title': 'lolkek', 'price': '1', 'url': 'keklol'}]

for x in data:
   writer.writerow((x['title'], x['price'], x['url']))
```

Comment: это парсер, в нем title, price, url..это переменные, они меняются и записываются через цикл но дублируются 3 раза

Comment: `def write_csv(data):
 with open('avito.csv', 'a') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(('price'))
  for i in data:
   # results = data['title', 'url', 'price']
   writer.writerow((data['price']))


def get_page_data(html):
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

 ads = soup.find_all('div', class_='item_table-wrapper')

 for ad in ads:
  #
  try:
   price = soup.find('div', class_='snippet-price-row').find('span', class_='snippet-price ').findAll(text = True)[0].strip()
  


  data = {'price': price}

  write_csv(data)` вот код

Comment: @Coder, спасибо за код. Я ничего не понял, больше так никогда не делайте.